# Integrating GWT with Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, gwt

I know that this topic was discussed many times, but I found that the most of information on this is not up to date.

I am looking for tutorial/example on how to integrate GWT with Spring framework.
I have found many examplex (some of them even working), but only with older libraries. I am looking for a solution with newest libraries (or at least compatible with the newest).

Also many examples use `spring4gwt` library (for creating "glue" servlet) - is there another way?

I want to create simple example application using `GWT + Spring + Hibernate + Maven`. I started by creating `Web Application Project` (from Eclipse). I converted project to Maven project. And to be honest I am stuck here. I can create simple service (+ async), but have no idea how to configure proper servlet and go further. Examples I found relay on spring4gwt, but I would like not to use it (no new version since 2009 I think).

It would be great if someone could explain integration step-by-step.

Sorry if this one is a duplicate, but after long search I haven't found clear solution that suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to integrate with Spring, but i think the best option is use [RestyGWT Framework](https://resty-gwt.github.io/)

Since you are using `HTTP` protocol and `JSON` format for serializing objects, you won't have problem to comunicate with the `Spring Controllers` using `RestyGWT`.

You could also use your own controllers to respond to `GWT RPC Requests`. Instead of using `GWT Dispatcher`, you use the `Spring MVC Request Dispacher` and map the URLS on controllers to your services in GWT client.

if you use the `RESTY GWT API`, you could just write your interface, map the methods using `JAX-RS` annotations like `@POST, @GET, @DELETE, @PathParam`, etc.

Here's what I'm doing on my project using `RestyGWT`:

The project is compose of 2 projects: 
project-client
project-server

The client contains all files related to `GWT` and `RestyGWT`.
The server contains all files from the back end implementation using `Spring`.

`Maven` overlay is used to merge the 2 projects on the package compile phase, so you end with a final war with the GWT *js files and the server files.

To use `RestyGWT` you have to create an interface who extends `RestService`:

```
   public interface MyRestService extends RestService{
   @GET
   @Path("/foo")
   public void getFoo(MethodCallback<List<Foo>);
   @POST
   @Path("/foo")
   public void saveFoo(Foo foo ,MethodCallback<MessageResponse>);
}
```

To use the service you write something like this:

```
MyRestService service = GWT.create(MyRestService.class);
```

and you will have something like this to use the service:

```
service.getFoo(new MethodCallBack<List<Foo>>(){
   public void onSucess(List<Foo> foos){
  /* You will get foos, you dont have to worry about serialization, RESTYGWT does it for you */
 }
 public void onError() ... 
 });
```

And you will have a controller to respond to this request like this:

```
@Controller
class myController{

 @Autowired FooService svc;

@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Foo> getAllFoos(){


   return svc.all();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces= "application/json", consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody MessageResponse save(@ResponseBody Foo foo){
   svc.save(foo);     
   return new MessageResponse("Foo saved with sucess", 200);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've created many projects with this setup, you don't need spring4gwt!
My solution is to use a "bridge" class that allow you to call async services like spring controllers:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public abstract class BaseRemoteService extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        ServletContextAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2470804603581328584L;
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        doPost(request, response);
        return null; // response handled by GWT RPC over XmlHttpRequest
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return this.servletContext;
    }
}
```

Now, your *RpcServiceImpl should be something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*/action.service")
public class ActionRpcServiceImpl extends BaseRemoteService implements ActionRpcService {
   //this class is managed by spring, so you can use @Autowired and other stuffs
   //implementation of your rpc service methods, 
}
```